# What is the use of declaring an ErrObject variable if there can only ever exist one error object?

Tags: vba, error-handling, ms-office

We all know there can only ever be one error object in VBA.
While helping a co-worker with error handling and why he shouldn't use `On Error Resume Next` I had an idea:
Store the error object somewhere to later reference back to it.

Consider this piece of test code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim t As ErrObject
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Raise 1
    Set t = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print t.Number
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Raise 1
    Debug.Print t.Number
End Sub
```

It will print 0 to the immediate window because `On Error GoTo 0` resets the error object and then prints 1 since it still holds a reference to the only error object (?).

If we create a new class and give it some properties pertaining to the ErrObject like so:

```
(TestClass)
Option Explicit
Public oError As ErrObject
Private Sub Class_Initialize(): End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    If Not oError Is Nothing Then Set oError = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get Error()
    Error = oError
End Property
Public Property Set Error(ByVal ErrorObject As ErrObject)
    Set oError = ErrorObject
End Property
```

And create our instance like this:

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim t As TestClass
    On Error Resume Next
    Set t = New TestClass
    Err.Raise 1
    Set t.Error = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print t.oError.Number
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Raise 1
    Debug.Print t.oError.Number
End Sub
```

We still get 0 and 1 as output respectively.

This bringst me to my question: **What is the use of declaring a variable as ErrObject when we cannot create a new object itself but it simply becomes another pointer to the only error object in VBA?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None whatsoever.

`Err` is often treated as some kind of global `ErrObject` instance, but the truth is, it's a function that *returns* one - as revealed in the object browser:

[image]

And that function is implemented in such a way, that you always get the same object.

Objects need to expose an interface to be usable, and so the object returned by the `Err` function exposes that of the `ErrObject` class - it doesn't mean the `ErrObject` class exists so that it can be instantiated or encapsulated by user code: it merely provides an interface to access the properties of the current run-time error state.

When you encapsulate an `ErrObject` like you did, you're essentially just giving yourself another way (besides the `Err` function) to access the `ErrObject` instance - but it's still the exact same object holding the properties of the *current run-time error state*.

And when an object's properties change, your encapsulated copy that points to that object is going to start reporting the new values, and the old ones you meant to "remember" are overwritten.

Note that this is true for any object, not just `ErrObject`.

Say I have a class that does what you're doing with the `ErrObject` reference, but with a `Collection`:

```
Private coll As Collection

Public Property Set InternalCollection(ByVal c As Collection)
    Set coll = c
End Property

Public Property Get InternalCollection() As Collection
    Set InternalCollection = coll
End Property
```

If I make an instance of that class (let's call it `Class1`) and assign `c` to its `InternalCollection`, and then add items to `c`...

```
Dim c As Collection
Set c = New Collection
With New Class1
    Set .InternalCollection = c

    c.Add 42
    .InternalCollection.Add 42

    Debug.Print .InternalCollection.Count
End With
```

The output is `2`, because `c` and `InternalCollection` (/the encapsuated `coll` reference) are the very same object, and that's what's happening with your encapsulated `ErrObject`.

The solution is to *not* encapsulate the `ErrObject` itself, but rather pull its values into backing fields for get-only properties that encapsulate the *state* of the `ErrObject`:

```
Private errNumber As Long
Private errDescription As String
'...

Public Sub SetErrorInfo() 'note: an ErrObject argument would be redundant!
    With Err
        errNumber = .Number
        errDescription = .Description
        '...
    End With
End Sub

Public Property Get Number() As Long
    Number = errNumber 
End Property

Public Property Get Description() As String
    Description = errDescription
End Property

'...
```

Now, whether that's useful is up for debate - IMO if the state is consumed at a moment where the global error state already contains the same information, there's no need to do this.

The class could pretty easily be [ab]used as a return type for a `Function` that returns `Nothing` to indicate success, and the encapsulated error state in case of failure - the problem is that the language is designed around *raising* errors rather than *returning* them; it's too easy to "fire-and-forget" such a function without verifying its return value, and since at the call site the *actual* runtime error state isn't going to trip an `On Error` statement, carrying error state as *program data* isn't idiomatic, it makes a "surprising" API that can easily result in code that ends up ignoring all errors.

Idiomatic error handling deals with the global runtime error state as soon as possible, and either recovers in the same scope, or lets the error state bubble up the call stack to where it can be handled. And until the error is handled, the `ErrObject` state is accessible through the global `Err` function.